# How to fix this error page with code 500 when trying to access http://localhost:8080/ords

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Not able to access the localhost:8080/ords URL.

1. Anonymous account is also unlocked.

java -jar ords.war standalone --port 8080 --apex-images D:\Tools\ords-19.1.0.092.1545\images

running above command in cmd and the server is getting started as well.
But still when i try to access

Not able to see the ords home page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the ORDS log file for more information about this error?  If you add the following to the `defaults.xml` configuration file of ORDS:

```
<entry key="debug.debugger">true</entry>

<entry key="degug.printDebugToScreen">true</entry>
```

And then try to reproduce the issue again. Hopefully, you can get some more detailed information about the cause of the error.

Comment: This is more a comment rather than an answer